# Javascript if statement to insert an image

Tags: javascript, image, function, if-statement

I'm very new to Javascript and trying to replicate something I do on a spreadsheet, but in javascript on a webpage, I've got it to work in a long winded way, looking for ways to simplify it.

The script is embedded within the HTML

```
<td class="td_Col11cSize">
  <div class="TableText">
    <span class = "Sub0a">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        if (Game2Player4Sub == "")
          document.write(Game2Player4Name, Game2Player4Off)
      </script>
    </span>
    <span class = "Sub1a">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        if (Game2Player4Sub == "Sub 1")
          document.write(Game2Player4Name, Game2Player4Off)
      </script>
    </span>
    <span class = "Sub2a">
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
        if (Game2Player4Sub == "Sub 2")
          document.write(Game2Player4Name, Game2Player4Off)
      </script>
    </span>
    <span class = "Sub3a">
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
        if (Game2Player4Sub == "Sub 3")
          document.write(Game2Player4Name, Game2Player4Off)
      </script>
    </span>
    <span class = "Sub4a">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        if (Game2Player4Sub == "Sub 4")
          document.write(Game2Player4Name, Game2Player4Off)
      </script>
    </span>
    <span class = "Sub5a">
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
        if (Game2Player4Sub == "Sub 5")
          document.write(Game2Player4Name, Game2Player4Off) 
      </script>
    </span>
    <span class = "Sub6a">
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
        if (Game2Player4Sub == "Sub 6")
          document.write(Game2Player4Name, Game2Player4Off)
      </script>
    </span>
    <span class = "Sub7a">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        if (Game2Player4Sub == "Sub 7")
          document.write(Game2Player4Name, Game2Player4Off)
      </script>
    </span>
  </div>
</td>
```

The code checks 8 conditions to set the font colour and add a player's name and time taken off in brackets. The above works, but is long winded and need to look at writting a function to replace it as its used 18 x 46 times on the page.

I also need to add another if statement to add `<img src ="YellowCard.png">` when `(Game2Player4Yellow == "n")`

Comment: 1. Please format and indent your code. 2. What did you try so far?

Comment: I'm lost as to how to make a function of this and then apply to all the instances. As for adding the yellow card image, I've not been able to get the syntax correct within Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using JS as if it was PHP...

Try something like:

```
function getGame2PlayerData(Game2Player4Sub, Game2Player4Yellow = null) {
    selector = Game2Player4Sub.replace(" ","") + 'a';
    elements = getElementsByClassName(selector);
    img = '';
    if (Game2Player4Yellow == 'n') {
        img = '<img src ="YellowCard.png">';
    }
    elements[0].innerHTML = img + Game2Player4Name + ' ' + Game2Player4Off;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Noy Gabay for the function idea. I'm not sure what the .replace (" ", "") + a; bit is intended to do.

Comment: Added the img condition. Since I have spotted that Game2Player4Sub is in the pattern Sub X and classnames are SubXa (where x is a variant), I decided to extract the required classname from the given parameter instead of hardcoding it. `.replace (" ", "")` just removes the spaces from the string.

Comment: Thank you, seems my syntax problems was not using "{" brackets to add the yellowcard image.

Comment: InnerHTML isn't a function it is a property.